# How to associate drupal content types with civicrm new group?

Tags: drupal, groups, acl

I have created the 10 contents(Article content type) in the Drupal.

And now, I want to associate these contents with new group in CiviCRM.

Please tell me how to associate these things ?

Comment: Thanks for your question. Could you say a bit more about what you are trying to achieve?  That will help people to provide better answers.

Comment: I am trying to create  blogs for a particular group. so that group members should see the blogs. I have created a new group in CiviCRM and also created a bunch of article pages in Drupal, But I don’t know how to associate this article pages to the civicrm new group

Comment: I'm still not clear what you are trying to achieve.  What do you mean by 'associate the articles to the group'? Do you want to limit access to these articles so that only people in the group can view them?

Comment: yeah william mortada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may also want to look at [Organic Groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og), which you can also [sync with civicrm](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Organic+Groups+CiviCRM+Synchronization), so a contact in a civicrm group is a member of an Organic Group, or vice versa. Then you can use OG as containers for your content. Probably not worth it if you only have a few pages of information.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to limit who can view content that you have added in Drupal.

To control access to Drupal content you need to create a role in Drupal and assign the correct permissions to this group.

More details here: [Users, roles and permissions](https://www.drupal.org/node/120614)

If you want to link the access to these articles with a specific group within CiviCRM you will have to synchronise the CiviCRM group with the Drupal role. You can do this using the CiviGroup Roles Sync module.

More details here: [CiviGroup Roles Sync](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/CiviGroup+Roles+Sync)